# Print case-identifier of discriminated union

Tags: .net, f#, discriminated-union

I have an `Option` type:

```
type Option<'a> =
    | Some of 'a
    | None

    override x.ToString() = sprintf "%A" x

printf "%A" None // "None"
printf "%A" (Some 1) // "Some 1"
```

Supposedly, in a function I want to print `Some 1`, but in another function I want to print its case-identifier, i.e. `Some` (discard the " 1" value). How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a generic way of doing it rather than implement a member for each of your types, you can use reflection for that:

```
open Microsoft.FSharp.Reflection

let caseLabel<'t> (x: 't) = 
    let typ = typeof<'t>
    if FSharpType.IsUnion(typ) 
        then
            let case, _ = FSharpValue.GetUnionFields(x, typ)
            Some case.Name
        else
            None
```

Comment: Note that if you change the signature to `caseLabel<'t>(x:'t)` and then use `typeof<'t>` instead of `x.GetType()` then it will work even with `None`.

Comment: +1 @scrwtp: interesting F# scoping bug, at least in my version, though if you try to use caseLabel in override x.ToString() = match caseLabel x with | Some(label) -> label | None -> ""

Comment: @sgtz: it's not really a bug - my version used runtime type information to get the DU type, and that was lost on nulls. kvb's improvement to that was to instead use static type information (through the generic type parameter rather than the potentially null argument value).

Comment: @scrwtp: not a bug with your code, but an F# bug related to using it from within "ToString". I posted an answer addressing this. Probably I should have just filed a comment and a link to the filed bug. My "what to do" evolved as I went along.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a match:

```
override x.ToString() = 
    match x with
    | Some _ -> "Some"
    | None -> "None"
```

To address your comment:
In this case I wouldn't override the ToString method, but instead do separate matches depending on the intended behavior. Or just define a helper function for printing an option without specifying content;

```
let printEmpty myOpt = 
    match myOpt  with
    | Some _ -> "Some"
    | None -> "None"
```

That way you could either use `sprintf "%A" myOpt` to print with content, or `printEmpty myOpt` to print without.

Comment: Let's say in this function I want to print `Some 1`, but in that function I want to print its case-identifier, i.e. `Some`, how can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, I'm including @scrwtp's version with a "type extension" form, rather than the original reimplementation of Option<'a>. The rationale being simply that the most recently defined type confused the use of caseLabel within the ToString portion (of the type Option<'a> definition in the original question).

NB. because we can't inherit from a DU (it has no constructors), we can't overload ToString. So extensions with ToString still default to the original ToString. Therefore, the static module style is probably more desirable, as we can explicitly access the new behaviour. Otherwise, the behaviour of sprintf / printf will access the original ToString, which is not what we want as per the question. I consider this a compiler bug. Bug filed over [here](https://github.com/fsharp/fslang-suggestions/issues/570)

btw: FSI pretty printing could alleviate this for FSI-only scenarios (TBD).

```
open Microsoft.FSharp.Reflection

let caseLabel (x:'x) = 
    typeof<'x> |> fun typ ->
      if FSharpType.IsUnion(typ) 
          then FSharpValue.GetUnionFields(x, typ) ||> fun case _ -> Some(case.Name)
          else None

type Option<'t> with 
  static member toString x = 
    match caseLabel x with
    | Some(label) -> label
    | None        -> "None"  

sprintf "%s" <| (Some 1 |> Option.toString)  // returns "Some"
sprintf "%s" <| (None |> Option.toString)    // returns "None"
```